# Search in MVC3 asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've multiple view page for search such as `searchArea.cshtml` for search by area, `searchCity.cshtml` for search by city and so on. i want to use a single action. in action i want to  switch case and a hidden field for search type like type=1 for area search, type=2 for city search and so on. this type will be used in switch case to indentify which category i want to search.i've a search action like

```
     public ActionResult SearchPost(string searchString,int searchType)
    {

        var posts= from s in db.posts.Include("user")
                       select s;
        switch (searchType)
        {
            case 1:
                posts = db.posts.Include("user").Where(i => i.area == searchString);
                break;
            case 2:
                posts = db.posts.Include("user").Where(i => i.city == searchString);
                break;
            case 3:
                posts = db.posts.Include("user").Where(i => i.garage == searchString);
                break;
            case 4:
                posts = db.posts.Include("user").Where(i => i.p_code == searchString);
                break;

        }
        return View(db.posts.ToList());
    }
```

i want to show result in a common view. Is there any ideas to implement it by a single view search page and a single view search result page???? is it possible??? thanks in advance...

Comment: What type of object is returned when search by city is used and when search by area is used?

Comment: Well, you action method is alright. You should be getting List<posts> in your SearchPost View. Have you tried `foreach` over the Model?

Comment: for all searches its will return same type of objects...

Comment: i'm getting  IEnumerable in my view.... i'need to know which type should i get for this problem

Comment: actually i've a view model(viewModel.postModel). i need to display this view model data in my view(.cshtml)page and i need to view my search option in the same page. this search will filter my view model data.i should i return this view data to my action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC Model Binding works fine on inputs that you code 'by hand' (i.e. not using the `@Html helpers`)

So, if you include a hidden field in your views, with a hard-coded value to correspond to you case statement, it should work just fine.

e.g. in `searchArea.cshtml` include

`<input type="hidden" name="searchString" value="1" />`

and corresponding fields in the rest of your views, and they should all be able to use the same action.